# 18.04 Mouse & Keyboard not showing in xinput but detected as USB devices

Tags: 18.04, usb, keyboard, mouse, xinput

(Ubuntu 18.04)
Hi, my mouse and keyboard suddenly stopped working. They work in BIOS and GRUB but not once Ubuntu GUI loads. Problem persists even after substituting another keyboard and mouse.

However, when I used an old LiveUSB 18.04 to boot, the mouse and keyboard work, which eliminates hardware problems.

In addition to mouse and keyboard other items like Power Button also show up in xinput's output, which do not when I boot normally. Literally nothing is there in xinput, see above

The USB mouse and keyboard are detected, but xinput does not show them:

```
hamid@hamid-threadripper:~$ xinput
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
hamid@hamid-threadripper:~$ lsusb
Bus 009 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 010 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 004: ID 1bcf:0005 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. Optical Mouse
Bus 005 Device 003: ID 05ac:021d Apple, Inc. Aluminum Mini Keyboard (ANSI)
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 05ac:1005 Apple, Inc. 
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 1e71:1714 NZXT 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
hamid@hamid-threadripper:~$ ll /dev/input/by-id
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 120 Feb  6 11:01 ./
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 460 Feb  6 11:01 ../
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   9 Feb  6 11:01 usb-1bcf_USB_Optical_Mouse-event-mouse -> ../event2
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   9 Feb  6 11:01 usb-1bcf_USB_Optical_Mouse-mouse -> ../mouse0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   9 Feb  6 11:01 usb-Apple_Inc._Apple_Keyboard-event-if01 -> ../event4
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   9 Feb  6 11:01 usb-Apple_Inc._Apple_Keyboard-event-kbd -> ../event3
```

How can I remedy this situation?
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I tried different keyboards and different USB ports to no avail. The other keyboards and mice were also detected but not work

Comment: I used an old LiveUSB 18.04 to boot and mouse and keyboard work. In addition to mouse and keyboard other items like Power Button also show up in xinput's output, which do not when I boot normally. Literally nothing is there in xinput, see above

Answer (score 0):

I ended up reinstalling Ubuntu.